# how to close current form but also close previous form when logout button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

When login button is clicked on form1, form2 will open, and when Go Form 3 button is clicked on form2, it will go to Form3. What I want to do is when the logout button in Form3 is clicked, Form3 and Form2 will be closed, so that i can display the Form1 only. I only know how to close the current form only which is this.Close();

[image: output]
 [image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is to subscribe to `FormClosed` `event` of  `Form3` on `Form2`, then inside the handler (inside `Form2`) simply write `this.Close()`.

If you open the `Form3` as modal with `ShowDialog()`, under the `Click` event handler of `LogoutButton` you can set the `DialogResult` of the `Form3` to `OK`, this will cause the modal form to be closed, then on `Form2` you can check the `DialogResult` and in case of "DialogResult.OK", you can close the `Form2`. Also instead of setting the `DialogResult` of the `Form3`, you can simply set the `DialogResult` property of the `logoutBottun` in the `VisualStudio` designer using properties window. This way you don't have to manually set the `DialogResult` of the `Form3` and you won't need the `LogoutButton_Click` event handler at all.

Here is a code sample for second approach:

On `Form3` this will go under `LogoutButton_Click` event handler:

```
    private void LogoutButtonOnForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

then on `Form2`, where you opened the `Form3` you should write st. like this:

```
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    if (f3.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.Close(); // this will close the form2
    }
```

Comment: I think I will try your first method, second method dun understand. I attached a image, am i correct with the codes? it doesn't work tho. When form3 logout button is clicked, it only closes the form3 form. For The private void Form3_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) I typed it out 1. @Arin Ghazarian

Comment: @Jordjmax oh yes, because you didn't open the form as modal. I think in your scenario its better to open the 'Form3' as modal with 'form.ShowDialog()' method.

Comment: So i changed to this in my form2. Still doesn;t work @Arin Ghazarian                                                            private void btnGoForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 form = new Form3();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }

Comment: @Jordjmax OK, I will edit my answer and write a code sample there in a moment.

Comment: U said loginbutton in form3. I think u meant logoutbutton. You gave the codes is fine except, there's a red line on the Login(); (Login does not exist in the current context.)  @Arin Ghazarian

Comment: @Jordjmax oh now I see, it is logout, so set the DialogReslut to DialogResult.OK and it'll be OK.

Comment: Ahh what should I do, i have attached a new image. @Arin Ghazarian

Answer (score 2):

The usual hang-up is to keep track of all the existing form objects.  A logout feature is an application global feature so it would be appropriate to make it a static method.  The Application.OpenForms property is useful to find form instances back.  A static method could look like this:

```
    public static void Logout() {
        for (int ix = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
            var frm = Application.OpenForms[ix];
            if (frm.GetType() != typeof(Form1)) frm.Close();
        }
    }
```

Note how iterating the OpenForms collection backwards like this is important, closing the forms alters the collection.  Now a logout button is simple:

```
    private void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Form1.Logout();
    }
```

Do rename the Form class to keep the code readable.  "Form1" should be, say, "MainWindow".